# How to download Github Raw CSV file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, github

I'm trying to grab an updated CSV file, [COVID-19](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv), that's posted on GitHub, but I keep getting an error that it's not there. It's a file that's constantly updated so I want to grab it at the source, which is GitHub.
[COVID-19 Time Series](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series) is the third item on the page.

I tried the raw file URL, the CSV page URL, and GitHub consistently tells me that there is "no such file or directory".

Here's my code:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

covids = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv"

puts File.exist?(covids)
keys = CSV.open(covids, &:readline)
```

How can I reference this file?  I know I am logged in, but Ruby should be able to see those file paths.

Comment: Your code and description don't agree; You say you want to access a remote file, but you don't try, you're trying to access a local one, which is why Ruby says it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL is not a file, so you can't open it with `CSV.open` neither use it in a `File.exist?` call. I see you've already included `open-uri` in your code, so the quick way to solve this would be to download the file using `open` and pass it to `CSV.open`:

```
keys = CSV.open(open(covids), &:readline)
puts keys
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer has some problems:

- OpenURI's `open` is deprecated. Instead use `URI.open`:

  ```
  pry(main)> open(covids)
  (pry):9: warning: calling URI.open via Kernel#open is deprecated, call URI.open directly or use URI#open
  ```
- `CSV.open`, while it works, is counter to the signature of the method, which wants a filename, not an IO object. It's conceivable that relying on `CSV.open` to continue taking an IO object will break in the future if they fix this behavior.

  Instead, the [CSV documentation's](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) first example recommends:

  ```
  csv = CSV.new(string_or_io, **options)

  # Reading: IO object should be open for read
  csv.read # => array of rows
  # or
  csv.each do |row|
    # ...
  end

  ...
  ```

  [`foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) is the form of `each` I'd use because that fits my brain better, YMMV:

  ```
  CSV.foreach(URI.open(covids))
  ```

  as a starting point. Here's an example looking at the first record in the file:

  ```
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'csv'

  covids = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv"

  CSV.foreach(URI.open(covids)).first
  # => ["Province/State",
  #     "Country/Region",
  #     "Lat",
  #     "Long",
  #     "1/22/20",
  #     "1/23/20",
  #     "1/24/20",
  #     "1/25/20",
  #     "1/26/20",
  #     "1/27/20",
  #     "1/28/20",
  #     "1/29/20",
  #     "1/30/20",
  #     "1/31/20",
  #     "2/1/20",
  #     "2/2/20",
  #     "2/3/20",
  #     "2/4/20",
  #     "2/5/20",
  #     "2/6/20",
  #     "2/7/20",
  #     "2/8/20",
  #     "2/9/20",
  #     "2/10/20",
  #     "2/11/20",
  #     "2/12/20",
  #     "2/13/20",
  #     "2/14/20",
  #     "2/15/20",
  #     "2/16/20",
  #     "2/17/20",
  #     "2/18/20",
  #     "2/19/20",
  #     "2/20/20",
  #     "2/21/20",
  #     "2/22/20",
  #     "2/23/20",
  #     "2/24/20",
  #     "2/25/20",
  #     "2/26/20",
  #     "2/27/20",
  #     "2/28/20",
  #     "2/29/20",
  #     "3/1/20",
  #     "3/2/20",
  #     "3/3/20",
  #     "3/4/20",
  #     "3/5/20",
  #     "3/6/20",
  #     "3/7/20",
  #     "3/8/20",
  #     "3/9/20",
  #     "3/10/20"]
  ```
- While OpenURI is convenient, it's not the most full-featured of the Ruby HTTP clients. I'd recommend working with something at the top of the [Ruby HTTP client list](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients).

  Also, write your code carefully so you don't beat your network or GitHub's following best practices for using `HEAD` requests to check the last time the file was updated; Don't repeatedly `GET` (download) a file that hasn't been updated because that's just bad network manners.

At this point you'd be prepared to parse the file, saving the information to disk or reusing it for something else. I'd recommend dumping it into a database for easier reuse using something like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/), which makes it trivial to build and access the schema and data of SQLite writing to a disk-based DB, or PostgreSQL or MySQL for more full-featured DBMs.

Comment: `CSV.foreach(URI.open(covids))` throws an error, saying `private method `open' called for URI:Module`.

Comment: Did you `require 'open-uri'`? If you `require 'uri'` you'll get that error.

Comment: That was it.  I thought `open-uri` is deprecated?  I'm running `ruby 2.6.5`.

Comment: OpenURI isn't deprecated, using the bare `open` method is: `>> open('http://www.example.com').read
(irb):2: warning: calling URI.open via Kernel#open is deprecated, call URI.open directly or use URI#open
=`. They're closing a security hole.